# SQL Server query, in order of higher number in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How would I write a query that only shows 10 pieces of data and only the highest number in the count column?

I'm thinking,

```
SELECT * 
FROM score 
WHERE count = (SELECT MAX(count) 
               FROM score 
               WHERE count <> (SELECT MAX(count) FROM score) TOP 10;
```

I know I'm almost there just not quite.

I am trying to show the top ten of the highest count from the score table.

Comment: Either you are trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be, or you are missing part of the information.  I've tried to address both these in my answer, but if i've missed something, let me know.

Comment: I am trying to get the highest score from count column to display with highest to lowest and only display 10. and I my be over complicating things.

Comment: Ok your first one runs through sql, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the scores and just want to see them in order:

```
SELECT 
  top 10 count 
FROM 
  score
order by count desc
```

To use an aggregate, you need to compare it against something.  If you have users for example:

```
SELECT 
  top 10 sum(count), u.userid
FROM 
  score s
  inner join users u on s.userid = u.userid
group by u.userid
order by sum(count) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM SCORE ORDER BY COUNT DESC TOP 10`

Or wherever `top 10` goes... will give top 10 scores.

`SELECT * FROM SCORE WHERE COUNT = (SELECT MAX(COUNT) FROM SCORE) TOP 10`

Top 10 rows having score equal max count.

Comment: In MS Sql Server, the `TOP` keyword is in the select.  It is the same as `LIMIT` in MySQL and others, but `LIMIT` is put at the end of the statement as you have done here.  This query wont run in MSSQL, or MySQL for that matter.